# Connection with boto to AWS hangs when running with crond

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron, boto

I have a very basic python script which uses `boto` to query the state of my EC2 instances. When I run it from console, it works fine and I'm happy. The problem is when I want to add some automation and run the script via `crond`. I notices that the script hangs and waits indefinitely for the connection. I saw that `boto` has this problem and that some people suggested to add some timeout value to `boto` config file. I couldn't understand how and where, I added manually `/etc/boto.cfg` file with the suggested timeout value (5) but it didn't help. With `strace` you can see that this configuration file is never being accessed. Any suggestions how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good chance that your cron environment is not close enough to the interactive shell of your login prompt.

Paths and things like .boto or boto.cfg files are not always found or in the same place in cron's environment.   Also, on some systems (ubuntu) cron runs as DASH and not BASH, so things will also be different.

If you are croning your script, try to source the /etc/boto.cfg file or set the AWS environment variables to make sure it's using the proper settings

Better yet - read them in to your python script making it portable and not reliant on env. vars.

```
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser, NoOptionError, NoSectionError
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

try:
   config = ConfigParser()
   config.readpf(open('/etc/boto.cfg', 'rb'))
   aws_seckey = config.get('Credentials', 'aws_secret_access_key')
   aws_keyid = config.get('Credentials', 'aws_access_key_id')
   conn = S3Connection(aws_keyid, aws_seckey)

except (IOError, NoSectionError, NoOptionError):     
   conn = S3Connection()  # try env if /etc/boto.cfg missing

except:
  raise
```

or something along those lines.  The key is to read the config instead of assuming the environment.

Comment: So I guess you answer is close enough. The environment variable http_proxy is defined for every user when he logs in to the system but cron daemon doesn't get it.

Comment: If you are certain of where the environment variable is sourced from (e.g. /etc/profile, /etc/bashrc, /etc/profile.d/http_proxy....) then you can source that in your cron.d script -or- you can set the variable in your cron command   For example, you could put a file in /etc/cron.d and have http_proxy='http://proxy' -or- . /etc/profile.d/proxy  .  man 5 crontab will help (see Example)

Comment: I simply set it using `os.envrion['http_proxy']` in side the python script, it works great and I don't need to worry about it anymore. Whenever the script runs it makes sure the the variable is set regardless of the context it is running from

Answer (score 1):

The entire issue appeared to be HTTP_PROXY environment variable. The variable was set in `/etc/bashrc` and all users got it this way but when cron jobs ran (as root) `/etc/bashrc` wasn't read and the variable wasn't set. By adding the variable to the configuration file of `crond` (via `crontab -e`) the issue was solved